# How do I change an automatic generated navigation bar Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have more than 5 tabs and thus giving me a table view cell with a navigation bar. How do I change the table view cell and the navigation bar.

Comment: Are you trying to say you have 5 tabs in your UITabBar and therefore you have a 'more navigation controller' representing the extra tabs?

Comment: Yes, is there a way I can change the color of tableview cell and the more button (the back button on navigation bar).

Comment: do you want to change navBarImage or back button?

Answer (score 1):

you can Set `UITableView` cell color like bellow UITableView Delegate Method:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:0.1];
```

}

And You can set Back button on UINavigationBar manually you just need to put this bellow code in to `ViewDidLoad` Method like:-

```
UIImage* imageback = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back_Button.png"];
                CGRect frameimgback = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
                backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimgback];
                [backButton setBackgroundImage:imageback forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButton];
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;
```

Hope its helps you thank you